# sbt-onejar and multi-project build

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-onejar

When using oneJar to package a multi project sbt build, project dependencies are not bundled into the jar. My setting is the following:

```
foo/build.sbt          (top-level build.sbt)
foo/src/               (sources of the root project)
foo/gui/build.sbt      (project 'build' definition)
foo/gui/src            (sources of the 'gui' project)
```

The build definitions are:

```
// foo/build.sbt

name := "foo"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

lazy val root = project.in( file(".") )

lazy val gui = project.in( file("gui") ).dependsOn( root )

[...]

//foo/gui/build.sbt

name := "foo-gui"

seq(com.github.retronym.SbtOneJar.oneJarSettings: _*)

[...]
```

When calling `oneJar` on the `gui` project everything seems to run fine, but the classes of the `root` project are not included in the jar (although the library dependencies are). Is there any fix ?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried a light configuration as you but shouldn't you put the oneJar settings in the root sbt file? You want to package the root and include guy right?

I tried something similar for the first time today and started with oneJar but when using a full sbt configuration the compiler complained that settings were a Seq(_) and sbt expected  a single setting or something like that. I switched to [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and it worked.

sbt-oneJar has not been updated for 2 years while sbt-assembly was recently updated. I'm not sure which one is preferred but I'd rather use an active tool.